# Perl STDOUT redirection not working in child

Tags: perl

While running following Perl program, the output of the child script is printed to the terminal instead of going into `$v`. Please let me know how to fix it.

```
open (OUTPUT, '>', \$v);
select OUTPUT;
$| = 1;

open (SUB, "| sh print_user_input.sh");
print SUB "Hello World\n";
close(SUB);

close(OUTPUT);
select STDOUT;

print "Output: $v\n";
```

The output of the program is:

Hello World
Output:

Comment: You should consider using lexical filehandles (like `$output`) rather than typeglobs (like `OUTPUT`), the 3-argument version of open (like `open my $sub, "|-", "./print_user_input.sh"`, `use autodie` to catch errors on `open` and `close`, and `use strict` if you are not already.

Answer (score 5):

1. `select` doesn't change STDOUT.
2. `open '>', \$buf` does not create a system file handle. (Who would read from it and place the data in `$buf`? Another process cannot write directly to `$buf`, even if were a `perl` a process.)

One solution:

```
use IPC::Run3 qw( run3 );
run3 [ 'sh', 'print_user_input.sh' ],
   \"Hello World\n",
   \my $v;
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got 2 problems.  [select](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) does not change STDOUT, it just changes Perl's idea of which filehandle it should be printing to.  And in-memory filehandles like you're trying to use only work inside a single Perl process; you can't use them in child processes.

You want to look at [IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aOpen3) or a similar module.

Comment: This would actually be hard with [IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Open3). It would require a `select` loop to avoid a deadlock. I recommend [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run3) or [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run). An example of this is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`IPC::Open2`](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aOpen2)'s `open2` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Open2;

my $pid = open2( \*CHLD_OUT, \*CHLD_IN, 'sh print_user_input.sh' );
print CHLD_OUT "Hello World\n";
close CHLD_OUT;

my $output = do { local $/; <CHLD_OUT> };
print "Output: $output";
```

Comment: Note that this can deadlock is `"Hello World\n"` is really a much longer string.

Comment: If the program kept going, you'd want to call `waitpid($pid, 0);` to reap the child. You might want to do that anyway to make sure the child ran successfully.